# Python PIP freezing and not working in Windows

Tags: python, pip

I am having trouble with PIP right now. When I installed python, I check the box to install pip together. Python itself works fine, but PIP does not work. Whenever I type pip in command line on Windows (no matter 8.1 or 10, I just fallback and re-upgrade my laptop), it will do nothing but keep freezing at this point and even ctrl-C is not working.
What should I do to solve this problem? I've tired to resintall python on 2.7.9, 2.7.10, 3.4.3, 3.5, they all have same problem, it seems not the python but some dll is missing(I guess).
[What it looks like when freezing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwY9a.png)

[What it looks like when calling with -v and install package('Django')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0mHY.png)

Comment: Did you specify what you want to install? It should be like   "pip install packx", where packx is name of package you try to install

Comment: could you please run `pip -v` and show output in here

Comment: There is still nothing shows up, even with -v or anything specificly assigned to install

Comment: First: You have do indicate the package, like `pip install xpto`. Second: Have you create a virtualenv? [Se here how to](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Because you can have many pip installed on computer. Other option is: try use a absolute path, some like E:\>Projects\Python\DjangoEnv\Scripts\pip.exe install xpto or easy_install.

Comment: Your firewall might be blocking pip

Answer (score 2):

Try `python -m pip install Django.` I had the same problem with pip today and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the log file created by the pip whenever you invoke the pip command. The log file is situated generally at

> C:\Users\user_name\pip

The notepad file will be created and you can verify what is missing